# Check and put in Hbase

Tags: performance, hbase

I have a case in which we need to insert records into Hbase table, in which 90% of the records coming from the source are repeated. In this case, 
is it advisable to first query for the record from Hbase, if not present then call put
or
just simply call put.

Which of the above will be good in terms of performance.

Answer (score 5):

Both HTable methods checkAndPut() and exists() requires accessing to table data which could hurt you badly if you receive lots of write requests and the data is not in the memstore.

Plain writes in HBase are usually not so expensive, so, if you have a good rowKey design and you're already avoiding hot regions, I'll just stick to overwriting data.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to re-insert existing records you can use the checkAndPut method of HTable. Which this the put will be applied only if the condition you specify is met. So you could check for an existence of a column to put only if not existing.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of agree with both answers. It is true that before using the `CAS`  (Check And Set) mechanism, one has to revise his design first, and see if it is possible to refactor it and use plain writes instead. However, in some cases, this is not trivial.

Another thing I would make sure of before using the `checkAndPut()`, is that this operation requires Isolation, when updating values. `HBase` only guarantees it, when rewriting, but not updating.

And at last, check if it is possible to use the `Append` instead of `checkAndPut`.